# Why doesn't my child element inherit color from its parent when parent has more specific selector?

Tags: css, inheritance, css-specificity

Why in the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/nz2ZT/) `world` is blue rather than red?

The specificity of `.my_class` is `0,0,1,0`, but it should inherit the color of `#my_id` whose specificity is *higher* at (`0,1,0,0`).

```css
#my_id {
    color: red;
}
.my_class {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p id='my_id'>
    Hello
    <span class='my_class'>
        world
    </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: [w3c: 6 Assigning property values, Cascading, and Inheritance - 6.2 Inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#inheritance)

An inherited value takes effect for an element **only if no other style declaration has been applied directly to the element.**

This style applies to an element with `id="my_id"`:

```
#my_id {
    color: red;
}
```

... and will apply (inherit) to an element nested within having `class="my_class"` *only if* its `color` property is otherwise unspecified.

...which no longer is the case once you declare:

```
.my_class {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Seems like if a child got affected by styles inside a *, the child also ignores its parent's style

Answer (score 3):

The reason this happens is due to inheritance, not specificity.

Look at it this way, if the span didn't have that class, it would inherit the color red from the parent <p> element and "world" would be red.  But note that that's due to inheritance.

When you set color for the span, via the class, that overrides the inherited value.

Specificity is for determining which rule to use in multiple competing rules.  In your example, there are no competing rules for <span>, so specificity does not come into play.  However, if you added this to your styles:

```
#my_id span {color: orange}
```

you would see that "world" is orange because of the specificity of the id being more than the class.

Answer (score 2):

It goes based on specificity and location. The class is applied directly to the text, but the ID is further away.

For a long explanation: http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to think of it, specificity order applies **at the same level**, if a style is on a parent *more local* then it applies, regardless of if an ancestor has a style with higher specificity (since it's further away, or less-local).